# Smbfile get last accessed date in java

Tags: java, file, io

I am working with shared files. I am using jcifs.jar library to get a list of shared files.

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(host, username, password);
SmbFile rootFile = new SmbFile(fullPath, authentication);
SmbFile[]  listFiles = root.listFiles();

for (int i = 0, i< listFiles.length;  i++) {
 SmbFile sf = listFiles[i];
 //I need to get last accessed date of each sf file.
}
```

How can I get the last accessed date of each 'sf' file?

**EDIT**

I case of java.io.File we can get last accessed date like this:

```
Path path = file.toPath();
BasicFileAttributes fattr = Files.readAttributes(path,   BasicFileAttributes.class);
LocalDate fileLastAccessed = Instant.ofEpochMilli(fattr.lastAccessTime().toMillis())
                        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: You can have a look at the version from https://github.com/googlegsa/filesystem.v3/tree/master/projects/jcifs which has that feature added by google

Answer (score 0):

There is no embedded method to check last access. The closest method to this is last modified:

```
 getDate
 public long getDate()
 This URLConnection method just returns the result of lastModified.
 Overrides:
 getDate in class java.net.URLConnection
 Returns:
 the last modified data as milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970
```